# A technical question concerning convolution product

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convolution

Let $v\in L^p(\Bbb R^d)$, $1\leq p<\infty$ be nonzero function, i.e., $v\not\equiv 0$.
Define $$u(x)= |v|*\phi(x)= \int_{\Bbb R^d} |v(y)|\phi(x-y)d y$$ with $\phi(x)= ce^{-|x|^2}$ and $c>0$ so that $\|\phi\|_{L^1(\Bbb R^d)}=1.$

Clearly we have $u\in L^p(\Bbb R^d)\cap L^\infty(\Bbb R^d)\cap C^\infty(\Bbb R^d)$, $u(x)>0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R^d$ and $u(x)\to 0$ as $|x|\to\infty$.

Question:

1. Is it possible that $u$ is nowhere locally constant, that is,
   **the following does not hold:**

$$\exists a\in \Bbb R^d, r>0 \quad \text{such that $u(x)= u(a)$ for all $x\in B(a,r)$?}$$

2. If not, can we find $\phi\in L^1(\Bbb R^d)$ such that
   $ |v|*\phi$ or $(|v|*e^{-|x|^2})*\phi$  is nowhere locally constant?

Note that we have the advantage that $|v|*e^{-|x|^2}\in L^p(\Bbb R^d)\cap L^\infty(\Bbb R^d)\cap C^\infty(\Bbb R^d)$

Comment: What about the case $v=\phi$?

Comment: I want $v$ to be arbitrary...

Comment: @PietroMajer Interesting remark. thx. I will update the second question.

Comment: (rewiriting) Note that 2 gives no more generality: $u_n=|v|*\phi^{(*n)}$, and $\phi^{(*n)}(x)=\phi(x/n)$. So $u_n(x)=[|v|*\phi(\cdot/n)](x)=[n^d|v|(n\cdot)*\phi](x/n)$.

Comment: $u$ is real analytic and thus cannot be locally constant (unless $u=0$).

Comment: @ChristianRemling How do you show that u is analytic?

Comment: Because $\phi$ is. For $v\in L^1$, this just follows from Morera + Fubini, for $p>1$ probably something more elaborate is needed.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I don't get it. I know  Morera only for Complex functions.

Comment: To show that $u(x)$ is real analytic, we must show that this function has a holomorphic extension $u(z)$ to a neighborhood of the real line. Make the obvious attempt $u(z)=\int |v|(t) \phi(z-t)\, dt$, $z\in\mathbb C$. Finally, apply Morera + Fubini to confirm that $u(z)$ is holomorphic.